# Creature design help - biological chemical ways for creatures to generate blizzards

Tags: biology, xenobiology, fauna

My organism has power to generate blizzards. It lives in a  planet full of methane and insulating gases.

My question is as to how it could generate a blizzard biologically. What compounds would be mixed to allow it to create this effect?

Comment: What do mean by "generate a blizzard biologically"? Are you talking about sever snowstorms with sustained high winds lasting for a prolonged period of time? Or are you talking about a cool VFX that someone thought up to give someone an ice attack in a game, movie, show, or manga?

Comment: Language ? It could be *lightning* is meant instead ? methane gas and insulators would do little with a blizzard (snow storm), the effect on lightning (range?) could be more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

If a horde of these creature could emit into their environment hydrochloric acid (HCl, or stomach acid) and baking soda (NaHCO3, a dry powder) they could create an area where the temperature would drop considerably. Creating an high pressure pocket of carbon dioxide filled air that would spread outwards. Creating both a sudden temperature drop and a chocking hazard.

This won't work well on a planet with temperatures much lower than room temperature.

There are more reactions like this but they involve substances in short supply to lifeforms on earth.

https://www.chemicool.com/examples/spontaneous-endothermic-reactions.html

Comparing it to a hurricane:

> If we start by looking at just the energy generated by the winds, we find that for a typical mature hurricane, we get numbers in the range of 1.5 x 10^12 Watts or 1.3 x 10^17 Joules/day (this is according to the Atlantic Oceanographic and Meteorological Laboratory.)

The reaction gives −40.5 kJ mol-1. That would mean that there has to been 3.2 x 10^12 mol of NaHCO3 and HCl in solution released. Assuming a high concentration of 30% HCL. That gives a weight of 653 milion tonnes.

653 milion tonnes of chemicals needed for a 1 day storm of freezing air.